# How to change the elements of forms depending on the selected value select, using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

For example there is a drop-down list:

```
<select>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
</select>
```

And there are, for example, 2 `<input type = "text" />`
How to make that when you select Item 2, add new input, or delete, using angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ng-model to the Select elements and show the element using ng-show  base on the condition

```
 <select ng-model='selectedValue'>
      <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
      <option value='2'>Item 2</option>
 </select>

<input  ng-show='(selectedValue == 2) ? true : false'  type = "text" />
```

***[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3k1Lvz0d/)***